# Create a local plugin in moodle/totara that enrolls users in every course on user creation and enroll all users on course creation

Tags: moodle, totara

how to create a local plugin in Moodle or Totara that enrolls users in every course on user creation and enroll all users on course creation.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this plugin : https://moodle.org/plugins/enrol_autoenrol

Or (depending on your needs) you can have a look at the cohort system.

You can sync cohort to courses and add users in this cohort. It will give access to all the courses that are linked to this cohort.
https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Cohort_sync